# Android Runtime execute adb to get logcat for certain Tag

Tags: java, android

I would like to obtain the certain tag log from logcat in android only. I have tried the following things and it works fine when i manually typed in command line.

`adb logcat -d` and
`adb logcat -s "MY_TAG"` both work fine.

When I test in the application by using

```
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb logcat -d");
        process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.append(line);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) v;
        tv.setText(log.toString());`
```

I am able to see the log in my textview.

However, when i change the command to

`Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb logcat -s \"MYTAG\"");`

I cannot get any update for my textview and the application shows no-response and ask me to wait or close it. I would like to see if any one experience this before and kindly address me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-d` option tells logcat to dump and exit.  If you leave it off, it stays running waiting for more logs.  Try adding `-d` back into your command --

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb logcat -d -s \"MYTAG\"");
```